# Security Implications of Deactivating Limited-access User Permission Lockdown Mode Feature

Tags: 2013, permissions, security, feature

There is a site collection on my farm that is accessible outside of our network but does not allow anonymous access.  Presently, we are experiencing some permissions issues where users need access to folders or libraries inside of the site without needing permission to the root sites themselves.  Of course, due to Limited-access user permission lockdown mode, this does not work as nicely as it could.  Turning this feature off should allow for the permissions to work as intended.

With that in mind, my question is: What are the security implications of having a site collection available on the internet and the permission lockdown mode deactivated?  Do I need to worry about it if I do not allow anonymous access to my sites?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-A2F2A5C2-093D-4897-8B7F-37F86D83DF04?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

This site lists the implications. However, note that it also impacts the SharePoint Server Publishing FEature, although MS isn't exactly specific about what it actually impacts in that feature.

Comment: Is it correct link?

Comment: @Raf Link seems to be working today

Comment: @BennySkogberg I know that the link is working. But the content of a linked page is not refers to the question.